# Literature request: Manifold that is defined by boundary condition of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I read "An elementary introduction to information geometry" of Frank Nielsen (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.08271.pdf), and I am very impressed by this theory.

Now, I am searching for some theory about manifolds that defined by solutions of partial differential equations (PDE). I suppose, Laplace equation with undetermined boundary condition defines some manifold of possible solutions.

I need a help from community, because Google Scholar and Google propose me articles about solution of PDE on manifolds, but not about manifolds defined by PDE solutions.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. Can you please elaborate on your example on Laplace equation, or point out which page(s) should one read in the link?